# changing value of checkbox from another component with ngmodel in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, frontend, ngmodel

i have two checkboxes on two separate component here is code for both
first:

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.status" [checked]="selectedUser.status | boolian" type="checkbox" >
```

second:

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="user.status | boolian"  ></td>
```

here is boolian pipe :

```
 transform(value: string, ):boolean {
     
    if(value === "active"){
      return true 
    } 
    else
    {
      return false
    }
  }
```

and here is ts code for first

```
@Input() selectedUser: any;


  @Output() onUserSubmit: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private datastorageService: DataStorageService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
  onSubmit(){
    //emit the value
    this.onUserSubmit.emit(); 
  }
```

and for second

```
selectedUser: any;


  ngOnInit() {
    //getting data from api
    this.DataStorageService.getPosts().subscribe((response) => {
      this.onuserdata = response;
      console.log(this.onuserdata)
    });
  }

  
  onUserSelect(user: any): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }
```

hope its enough

im trying that when first checkbox is toggled another one is emited same way, second checkbox is disabled so user can only change one
selectedUser.status and user.status have same value both is coming from api which provide "active" and "inactive" string and with pipe i tryed to change it to true and false in short im trying to have user status showed with checkbox, active user is checked and inactive unchecked, and that u can change it from edit component hope i Explained good enough :D

Comment: Is second the parent of first?

Comment: For checkboxes you need to use `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="selectedUser.status | boolian" (change)="onStatusChange($event)">` with `onStatusChange(ev: any) { selectedUser.status = ev.target.checked ? 'active' : 'inactive'; }`

Comment: `ngModelChange` doesn't trigger at the correct moment. The `(change)` event from the `FormsModule` in fact does